# PhoneGap error: jar: invalid option -- 'e'

Tags: java, android, cordova, ubuntu, jar

While I try to create an android phonegap app I get the following error:
    $ phonegap/lib/android/bin/create myapp
    invalid option -- 'e'
    Try `jar --help' for more information

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jar was throwing this error because I was using the wrong jar (the sun sdk one)

I fixed this problem by simply running:

```
 $ sudo update-alternatives --config jar
```

and selecting oracles jar:

```
Selection    Path                                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/fastjar                     100       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/fastjar                     100       manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jar   2         manual mode
```